# How to echo only specified text to download in PHP

Tags: php, http-headers, download

I have some php code that looks like:

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo 'test';
```

After this block the view is loaded to render the html for the page to be displayed.

The problem is that all the html on the page afterward is also part of the file download.  How can I resume normal browser output so that only the echoed text is sent to the file download?

Comment: Echo before the Header content.

Comment: So you're looking for a way to stop a script from executing the code after a specific point? Try [`exit()`](http://www.php.net/exit).

Comment: @Vincius - sorry that doesn't make sense.  I want to echoed text to be included in the download.  just not everything after it.

Comment: @hanzi - that doesn't work in this case.  the rest of the webpage is displayed after the file download so it's still included in the file.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for something akin to the `Content-type: multipart/mixed;` of email, but for the web. Unfortunately it doesn't exist. Another route to explore would be [HTTP pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining), but it might not be supported by client browser.

Comment: @hanzi - sorry, using the exit statement does indeed work.  I must have done something wrong before.  feel free to submit this as an answer.

Comment: I think the only solution is that you first display the HTML page and include something like `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.org/myDownloadScript.php">` in the HTML head element that includes the download code you posted above. [see also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)